# How to use two connection strings on development vs production

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, web-config

I have two connection strings in my Web.config.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mokey;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AuthContextMySQL" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="database=mokey;persistsecurityinfo=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I can specify which one to use in code like this:

```
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AuthContext()
        : base("AuthContextMySQL")
    {
    }
}
```

How do I specify which one to use depending on development vs production?

Comment: Assuming your using VS, you can have multiple `web.config.cs` files - refer [this article](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706477/how-to-separate-between-debug-and-release-for-connections-etc-in-mvc4]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [web.config transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) during your build step to add/update/delete sections of your web.config depending on the build configuration. See [this article](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100) for a step by step guide.

Comment: So I should have one connection string that is transformed for debug vs release?

Comment: You would typically put the development connection string into the web.config file. Then, you would have another `web.production.config` file that you would use to change it during the build/publish step. They should have exactly the same name so your code is completely unaware of the change.